# Finding Credentials for connected Apps

Tags: connected-apps

I got a user that can't connect to SF from the Tablette Application, a custom App ;

I sent him this credentials :
[image]

The Tablette Application is in connected Apps :
[image]

And when I Manage it, I find this and that's what I transmitted :
[image]

But I see that I have 'Token Valid for 0 hour'
And I'm not sure of the use of 'Initial Access Token for Dynamic Client Registration' ...

I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not used to connecting apps, I'm reading documentations but can't understand why the data I gave to the user of the connected App didn't work !

EDIT 26/06/2019 :

I'm trying with SOAPUI but still nothing,
I read [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) article, and this is the results :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The value of *password* is a concatenation of the password and security token for the user account that you're wielding to obtain the access token. See the Note paragraph in the middle of the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) page

Comment: I read this (*) also, but still can't connect (trying with SoapUI)
I'm editing my question .
Thanks for helpîng !
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

We got the wrong securitytoken...
After reseting it, all went well !
Thanks for helping !

For the record, [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) is perfect